# Space objects visible from earth

Tags: space, deep-sky-observing

I recently saw the International Space Station without a telescope. Are there any other man-made space objects that can be seen using bare eyes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are [quite a lot of them](http://www.n2yo.com/satellites/?c=1&srt=4&dir=1), but ISS is by far the brightest. The other satellites can be visible with magnitude fainter than 3. "Can be" means in dusk/dawn, when the satellite is in the sunlight.

Comment: Iridium flashes can be pretty bright even in the daytime.